# Perl uninitialized value error

Tags: perl

I have written the following piece of code to try and print out values in a hashref. The hashref is coming from a DBI `$statement->fetchrow_hashref()` method.

I want to use a `"string + $variable"` key for accessing the element's value. When I run the code I get the following error:

> Use of uninitialized value $value in string eq at main.pl line 19.

I thought I was checking the value before trying to use it, so I don't know how else to catch that element `test3` is empty.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# list is actually a hashref from DBI query
my $list = {"test1" => 'true=yes', "test2" => 'false=no', "test3" => ''};
my $value = "";

my_function($list);

sub my_function {

    my ($list) = @_;

    # Loop through values
    foreach my $i(1..6) {

        $value = $list->{"test$i"};

        if(undef $value || $value eq "") {
            next;
        }

        my ($k, $v) = split('=', $value);

        print "$k = $v\n";
    }
}
```

Also I'm curious about the difference between a hashref and a regular hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call `undef $value` *sets* `$value` to `undef`.

You need to use `defined` instead, like this

```
if (not defined $value or $value eq "") {
  next;
}
```

or

```
next unless defined $value and $value ne '';
```

Note also that the only Perl *false* values apart from `undef` and the null string are the value zero and the string `"0"`, so the easiest way to exclude all of these is just

```
next unless $value;
```

but in your case this would also exclude elements like `test4 => 0` and `test5 => '0'`, which you may not want.

Comment: Alternatives: `next if !defined($value) || !length($value);` [before 5.12] and `next if !length($value);` [5.12+]

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to have `next unless length $value;`